# Converting Country Codes to Country Names

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I need to convert a list of country codes to a country array. Here is what I have done so far.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    pickerViewArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //pickerViewArray is of type NSArray;
    pickerViewArray =[NSLocale ISOCountryCodes];
}
```

Comment: Sorry , it is of type NSMutableArray;

Answer (score 57):

You can get an identifier for a country code with `localeIdentifierFromComponents:` and then get its `displayName`.

So to create an array with country names you can do:

```
NSMutableArray *countries = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: [[NSLocale ISOCountryCodes] count]];

for (NSString *countryCode in [NSLocale ISOCountryCodes])
{
    NSString *identifier = [NSLocale localeIdentifierFromComponents: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: countryCode forKey: NSLocaleCountryCode]];
    NSString *country = [[NSLocale currentLocale] displayNameForKey: NSLocaleIdentifier value: identifier];
    [countries addObject: country];
}
```

To sort it alphabetically you can add

```
NSArray *sortedCountries = [countries sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

*Note that the sorted array is immutable.*

Comment: Thanks but the list is not Sorted ! how to do that ?

Comment: I edited my answer assuming you want to sort it alphabetically.

Comment: In iOS8 `country` is nil.

Comment: That is returning the country language name. I would like to get the country name

Answer (score 25):

This will work in iOS8 :

```
NSArray *countryCodes = [NSLocale ISOCountryCodes];
NSMutableArray *tmp = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[countryCodes count]];
for (NSString *countryCode in countryCodes)
{
    NSString *country = [[NSLocale systemLocale] displayNameForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode value:countryCode];
    [tmp addObject: country];  
}
```

Answer (score 24):

In Swift 3 the Foundation overlay changed quite a bit.

```
let countryName = Locale.current.localizedString(forRegionCode: countryCode)
```

If you would like country names in different languages you can specify the desired locale:

```
let locale = Locale(identifier: "es_ES") // Country names in Spanish
let countryName = locale.localizedString(forRegionCode: countryCode)
```

Answer (score 6):

In iOS 9 and above you can retrieve the country name from the country code by doing:

```
NSString *countryName = [[NSLocale systemLocale] displayNameForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode value:countryCode];
```

Where `countryCode` is obviously the country code. (e.g: "US")