# Convert state name of a country to ISO code in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslocale

I am using an API for getting data based on state's ISO code. For example, Haryana = HR, California - CA. Here, I don't know how to get state's name in ISO format (2 letter). Please help me regarding this

Comment: Please review this link .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12671829/get-country-code-from-country-name-in-ios

Comment: Thanks.... But, this will work fine for country and language

Comment: I need same ISO code for particular country... How can I get that ?

Comment: you are required multi record?

Comment: I need to get state code using full state name. Example, Haryana - HR, Delhi - DL. Please help me with this... Thanks

Comment: you are use geocoding or without geocoding?

Comment: I am using without Geocoding