# How to get Country Code from Country Name Using Swift?

Tags: swift

My scenario, I am trying to get country code by using country name. I tried below code but Its only getting country name.

```
func countryName(from countryCode: String) -> String {
    if let name = (Locale.current as NSLocale).displayName(forKey: .countryCode, value: countryCode) {
        // Country name was found
        return name
    } else {
        // Country name cannot be found
        return countryCode
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code gets the country name from the country code, not the opposite as you claim and it works fine when I test it. Please clarify what you are asking.

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/a/48790731 solve your problem?

Comment: @MartinR I tried but its working only for apple supported country. I need to get all country.

Comment: @jackios: Unless I am mistaken, “Afrikaans” is a language and not a country.

Comment: @MartinR okey try "South Africa"

Comment: @MartinR I am expecting pass the country name to get country code.

Comment: If Locale doesn’t support all countries you need then you need to find and use some Rest API or similar

Comment: When reviewing the Swift answers in the duplicate, be sure to note that most of them are flawed or out-of-date. Choose wisely among the answers.

Answer (score -2):

```
if let countryCode = (Locale.current as NSLocale).object(forKey: .countryCode) as? String {
   return countryCode
}
```

Comment: You can just do
 `return ((Locale.current as NSLocale).object(forKey: .countryCode) as? String) ?? countryCode` in one line

Comment: Answers are more helpful if they *explain* the problem and the solution, instead of posting code only.